# Vue router change query on current route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a URL I'm appending attribute parameters to using this code:

```
this.$router.push({ query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, { attributes: this.encodedAttributes() }) });
```

When I call that method the second time, the parameters get added again.  But I want it to update rather than adding another time if there are already attribute parameters. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you a post a https://codesandbox.io showing this?  I can't reproduce the behavior

Comment: @Dan: I have added code : https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-snow-n41lf?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue, can you please check only thing i want i when clicking on the button attributes parameter should append to the current url and if attribute parameter already exists it should update that parameter rather than adding another attribute parameter to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Referring to the code link in comments) Putting a stringified array into a query param will not convert it to query params.  It's also part of a nested object which also wouldn't work.

Make `dynamic_fields` an object:

```js
data() {
  return {
    dynamic_fields: {},
  };
},
```

Remove `encodedAttributes` and change `search`:

```js
search() {
   this.$router.push({ query: this.dynamic_fields })
      .catch(failure => false);
}
```

`.catch` on `$router` push prevents the navigation failure error.

Here is an [updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-65008595-forked-xwf4z?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i'm pressing new url button and if there is no attribute like `https://qp63o.csb.app/` or  `https://qp63o.csb.app/?attr0=0&attr1=1` (not complete attribute parameter attr2=2 is removed)  so pressing new url button should update attribute parameter to the url.

Comment: Pressing the button adds the parameters.  I thought that's what you wanted.  If you want to change them, change `dynamic_fields` and press the button.

Comment: Okay, I will try that

Comment: It is working in all cases except one, when i manually try to remove last parameter t.e. attr3=3 now when i press new url button now the att3 should gets appended to the existing url, Is it possible in vue.js?

Comment: yes i'm using for loop because i will get new attributes using that loop